# Access async store data before vue-router runs beforeEach (navigation guard)

Tags: async-await, vuex, action, vue-router

I want to use a navigation guard but my store data is async and its allways to late, so the beforeEach runs before  my auth status is loaded. I tried to load my auth status in the created() hook of my vue app, then I tried to load it before new Vue in main.js or in router.js before the beforeEach runs... I even tried it with waiting for the promise...

Here my async action

```
export default {
async setIsAuthenticated(context) {
    await auth.onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
        if (user) {
            context.commit('setIsAuthenticated', true);
            context.dispatch('user/setUserData', user.uid, {
                root: true,
            }); 
        } 
    });
}
```

The setIsAuthenticated action triggers this mutation

```
    setIsAuthenticated(state, payload) {
        state.isAuthenticated = payload;
},
```

This is my router.js beforeEach()

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
if (to.path !== '/userauth' && !store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']) {
    next('/userauth'):
} else {
    next();
}
```

And I tried to dispatch at it with waiting for the promise

```
store.dispatch('auth/setIsAuthenticated').then(log => {
console.log(log); 
});
console.log(store.getters['auth/isAuthenticated']);
```

But isAuthenticated is allways null. Only when the site is completely loaded I can console.log it and its true

Comment: Question is unclear:  if you run authorization code before `beforeEach` ever runs, when/where does the user get a chance to login?

Answer (score 0):

I already found a solution. Maybe it will help someone:

I created a init action that returns a promise and dispatches my action which gets me the auth status before I do anything else.

```
    store.dispatch('init').then(() => {
       new Vue({
          vuetify,
          router,
          store,
          render: h => h(App),
       }).$mount('#app');
    });
```

And this is the action init:

```
  actions: {
    init(context) {
        return new Promise(resolve => {
            setTimeout(() => {
                context.dispatch('auth/setIsAuthenticated', null, {
                    root: true,
                });
                resolve('Done');
            }, 1000);
        });
    },
```